# slurm: Priotizing jobs by that has lower tasks

Tags: slurm, qos

I'm very new to Slurm, i checked out the QoS documentations about that but I need to get advises from experienced Slurm users.

To explain the title, let's consider someone queued a long job that has 300 subtasks on it to our Slurm service. After that, someone else queued a job that has 3 subtasks. Since our default configuration runs on FIFO model, the job that has 3 subtasks will never be done unless the job that has 300 subtasks finished. This doesn't seem a fair way in our work plan, so we need to queue the 3 subtasks job as prior to 300 subtasks job even it is queued later.

Since I'm new to Slurm, I don't know the terms so much, so I had no idea to what to google, thank you.

And I was looking for these documentation, I'm in doubt about I'm looking to correct documentations:

https://slurm.schedmd.com/qos.html

https://slurm.schedmd.com/resource_limits.html

Job QoS limit seems a very similar to my topic.

Comment: Could you please tell me what does it meant by subtasks (tasks in job array etc etc)? Also how is it estimated that time taken for 300 subtasks > 3  subtasks? There could be porential cases where time taken for 3 subtasks is longer than small 300 subtasks? Is that assumption wrong?

Comment: @j23 Of course, I'm sorry again because I'm new to slurm glossary. I meant subtasks as individual tasks in a batch job. I wasn't aware of 300 subtasked batch can require more time than 3 subtasked batch, so thank you for mentioning that. But lets say each subtask has the same computational time. In that case, how can I prioritize 3 subtasked batch job to 300 subtasked batch job if even 3 subtasked job queued very later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood about the question, you need to take the number of tasks/job steps (say, srun calls) into the consideration for using priority and scheduling.

If my undertstanding is correct, Slurm doesn't take this characteristic (number of srun calls) for priority and scheduling. This is because, the characteristic of tasks cannot be estimated from the task syntax. Using historical data, you can indeed estimate but per job granularity not task granularity- slurm uses this for advanced scheduling. (Except the application developer, nobody can estimate the time taken for two tasks simply by looking the task definition).

For example, consider your scenario with one job having 300 tasks (300 srun call or so) and another with 3 tasks.

Case 1:

Assume that each job got 1 node (say with 24 cores). Your first job finished 300 tasks using 24 cores in 1hour and second job finish 3 task in same duration of time using same number of cores. Here what slurm sees is that (accounting is enabled), both your application used same number of resources.

Case 2:

Assume that each job got 1 node (say with 24 cores). Your first job finished 300 tasks using 24 cores in 1 hour and second job finished 3 tasks in 3 minutes. Here also what slurm sees that both your application is completely utilising the resources - per job granularity.

How can slurm understand the difference between case 1 and case 2? It cannot, because both are utilising all the resources (the same number of nodes) and slurm scheduling won't consider the number of tasks/job steps for priority as well as scheduling.

In other words it doesn't make sense to use the number of tasks metrics because a job with **large** 3 tasks can take more time than a job with **small** 300 tasks and vice versa. Here slurm cannot estimate **large** and **small** based on the number of tasks because it is application dependent.

So coming back to your problem, we could think this with respective to time and resources. You could create partition in which say **small** partition can run the jobs that is less than 30 mins while **large** partition can run the jobs greater than an hour. And you set higher priority to jobs requiring in **small** partition during scheduling. This is one way to look into the issue and most centers use this concept.

If you go for [multifactor](https://slurm.schedmd.com/priority_multifactor.html#mfjppintro) priority Slurm wil consider Age (waiting in the queue duration), Association fair-share etc to schedule the job but stll Slurm wont consider the number of tasks even in this case. You can set the priority flags to consider the time (using *PriorityFavorSmall* and *SMALL_RELATIVE_TO_TIME* in *multifactor priority*) but this is calculated with respect to the job size (number of nodes).

**In short**: **You should create different partitions based on job time requirements and priority should be given to partition with smaller time duration. In job script, hence the smaller jobs can use the smaller partitions and get faster allocation.**

*Assumption from my side: Both jobs (300 tasks and 3 tasks) uses same number of nodes and cpus. If larger jobs uses more CPUS in a node than smaller jobs, there are other approaches (fair-share etc)*

Comment: Thank you very much, your reply has very inspired my approaches on the topic. It's seems really good idea to divide jobs to partitions by their heaviness if we assume smaller jobs can take more time even than larger jobs.

But so what we should do (aka how we should use fair-share mechanism) if we are talking about larger jobs use more cores and smaller jobs use less cores?

Comment: Welcome. If it helped you can accept the answer :) To achieve your objective you can use **PriorityFavorSmall** flag in **multifactor priority**. _PriorityFavorSmall: A boolean that sets the polarity of the job size factor. The default setting is NO which results in larger node sizes having a larger job size factor. Setting this parameter to YES means that the smaller the job, the greater the job size factor will be._ [See for more] (https://slurm.schedmd.com/priority_multifactor.html#mfjppintro)